Better optimization of bounds on sums of Pauli strings?
I'm trying to bound a quantity $||\sum_i \alpha_i P_i ||$ where the $P_i$ are arbitrary Pauli strings, $||.||$ is the operator norm (max eigenvalue) and $\alpha_i$ are arbitrary real coefficients.
If there are $N$ Pauli strings in the sum, we can trivially bound this quickly using the triangle inequality as $\leq \sum_i |\alpha_i| ||P_i|| = \sum_i |\alpha_i|$, but this is obviously not optimal in general.
Are there any ways of getting a better bound that would require solving the exponentially large matrix  $\sum_i \alpha_i P_i$?
One potential is to use that fact that we can write $||\sum_i \alpha_i P_i || = \max_\rho \sum_i \alpha_i tr[P_i \rho]$. If we decompose the state in terms of Pauli strings $\rho = \sum_j\beta_j P_j$, and hence we can write:
$$ ||\sum_i \alpha_i P_i || = max_{\beta_i} \sum_{ij} \beta_j \alpha_i tr[P_iP_j] =  |max_{\beta_i}\sum_i \alpha_i \beta_i |. $$
Here we have used $tr[P_iP_j] = \delta_{ij}$. Using $tr[\rho]=tr[\rho^2]=1$, we have the constraints $\sum_i \beta_i=1$ and $\sum_i |\beta_i|^2 = 1$, so we can phrase this as an optimization problem.
However, it's not totally clear that this is a useful expression as there can generally be exponentially many $\beta_i$ which may make the computation intractable. Can we do better?

Which norm? For the 2-norm, the norm just equals the 2-norm of the alpha.

You're saying, the max eigenvalue satisfies $\lambda_{max}( \sum_i \alpha_i P_i) \leq \sqrt{ \sum_i |\alpha_i|
^2 }$?

No, all 2-norms, with equality. (Which implies the above.)

@NorbertSchuch Isnt that no longer true for pauli strings? If we had the sum $XX + ZZ$, the max eigenvalue is $2$ not $\sqrt{2}$, because there is a simulatneous $+1$ eigenvector $v$ s.t. $XXv = v$ and $ZZv = v$. If we had a sum of all anti-commuting paulis, then its the 2-norm of the alphas.

Right, you have to normalize the Paulis with $1/\sqrt{2}$ (so they are orthonormal), i.e. there is a prefactor $2^{-n/2}$.
